# как получить данные из всей строки таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как получить данные из всей строки таблицы т.е нажал я на кнопку1 и получил данные из ячеек со значениями one two,а нажал на кнопку2 получил 3 и 4

```js
           $("tr").click(".btn", function(e) {
             val = $(this).text();
             alert(val);
           })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn">кнопка1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn">кнопка2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

**Обновление**

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var tdVals = $(this).parent('td').siblings('td').map(function(i, td){
        return $(td).text();
     })
    console.log(tdVals);
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо выбирать элементы относительно кнопки на которой произошло нажатие. Далее в цикле Вы можете обрабатывать каждую ячейку.

```
$("button").on("click", function(event, elem){
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td").each(function(idx, itm){
        console.log(itm);
    });
});
```